# kernel_task Virtual Memory Size too high

Tags: memory, performance, kernel

I'm using MacBook Pro ("Core i7" 2.5 15" Mid-2015 (DG) 2.5 GHz Core i7 (I7-4870HQ) 16GB RAM) with MacOS Sierra 10.12.4 on it. After connecting a new LG 34UC98 Monitor I faced some heat problems and started investigations. First thing that was really strange for me is this:

[image]

As you can see the Virtual Memory Size is to way higher then the Real one.

Is this normal/expected behavior and how can I wipe/clear this and avoid such kind of memory load in the future?

PS: Attaching Statistics as well:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior.

You can do nothing to wipe/clean it - except rebooting your computer.

There's no benefit from wiping/cleaning it, and no disadvantage from kernel_task having a high virtual memory size in itself. There's no real point in trying to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do you know how user can control this behavior?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. What reason could you have for controlling it? This is the way the operating system works - this is how most modern operating systems work.

Comment: Sence is to know how user can control it (if possible).

Comment: That is not sense. You need to provide a reason for wanting to control it. I'm pretty sure this is all because you have some misunderstanding that you think you can "gain resources" or "gain speed" if you control this. You can't.

Comment: Because of some misunderstanding I've asked this question. Will made more researches on this. Thanks.